# pdf export from quickreport in Delphi for Arabic language

Tags: delphi, pdf, arabic

I used below codes for exporting pdf file from quickreport in Delphi:

```
pdf:=TPdfDocument.Create;
       try
           QRep.Prepare;
           for i:=1 to QRep.QRPrinter.PageCount do begin
               aMeta := QRep.QRPrinter.GetPage(i);
               try
                   pdf.DefaultPageWidth := MulDiv(aMeta.Width, 72, pdf.ScreenLogPixels);
                   pdf.DefaultPageHeight := MulDiv(aMeta.Height, 72, pdf.ScreenLogPixels);
                   pdf.AddPage;
                   pdf.Canvas.RenderMetaFile(aMeta,1,0,0);
               finally
                   aMeta.Free;
               end;
           end;
           pdf.SaveToFile(fileName);
       finally
           pdf.Free;
       end;
```

but it doesn't work good for Arabic language characters.
In the created pdf file, the letters of Arabic words are separated and in the inverse order. but the English words are ok.
how can I fix it?

I want to convert a quickreport to a pdf file format by Delphi for Arabic language

Comment: "doesn't work good" is a bit vague.

Comment: How are we supposed to use *doesn't work good*? We can't read your mind or see your screen to know what that means. It's your responsibility to **clearly and specifically** describe the problem you're having, so that we have enough information to try to help. If you don't make the effort to explain what's wrong, we can't help you, and you'll have to figure it out yourself.

Comment: excuse me that I said vague. In the created pdf file, the letters of Arabic words are separated and in the inverse order. but the English words are ok.